# Expo camera zoom

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

That's my first time using the Pinch Gesture Handler in React Native... I'm trying to create a zoomable camera using Expo. What i'm doing is:

```
const handlePinch = (nativeEvent) => {
   const { scale, velocity } = nativeEvent;

   let newZoom =
     velocity > 0
       ? zoom + scale * velocity * (Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0.01 : 25)
       : zoom -
         scale * Math.abs(velocity) * (Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0.02 : 50);

   if (newZoom < 0) newZoom = 0;
   else if (newZoom > 0.5) newZoom = 0.5;

   setZoom(newZoom);
};

...

<ExpoCamera
    ...
    zoom={zoom}
    ...
  >
```

Working but not too smoothy... Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue?